# I need to vailidate user input and have user reenter if invalid in java

Tags: java, validation, try-catch

I have to validate my user input for an integer value and prompt the user to reenter if an invalid value is entered. Thus far I have put together this method below. i believe the logic is correct but I need to get the user to reenter input again after the error message.

```
void validateItemquantity() {
    boolean error = true;
    while (error) {
        try{ 
            Integer.parseInt(itemQuantityinput.getText());
            error = false; 
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Item quantity must be a positive number, please reenter");
            error = true; 
        }
    }
}
```

Part of code from jframe method:

```
private void bnPurchaseActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           

        String itemCode; 
        int itemQuantity, itemPrice, itemCost, totalCost ;

        validateItemquantity();
        itemCode = itemCodeinput.getText();
        itemQuantity = Integer.parseInt(itemQuantityinput.getText());
        itemPrice = catalog.searchCatalog(itemCode);
        itemCost = payment.calculateItemcost(itemQuantity,itemPrice);
        totalCost = payment.calculateTotalcost(itemCost);
```

Comment: Should we assume this is java??

Comment: yes its java..sorry about that.

Comment: maybe the loop should be outside the method. you need to make multiple calls the the `validateItemquantity` method, and perform each check. Can you show the code which calls this method?

Comment: itemQuantityinput looks like a textfield. Are you building a Swing form for the input? Then the validation should be attached to some event on the JTextField or on the form's button. If you are doing console app then this loop might be more appropriate.

Comment: Hi Vincent - You were a guess lecturer on Scrum in my Saturday class a couple weeks aback.  Thanks for your help, but how do I get back an input from the textfield? Trying to understand this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the loop should be in the calling method.

```
boolean validateItemquantity() {
    try{ 
        Integer.parseInt(itemQuantityinput.getText());
        return true; 
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Item quantity must be a positive number, please reenter");
        error = false; 
    }
}
```

And the calling part should be something like that

```
while(!validateItemquantity())
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but how do I get back an input from the textfield?

Comment: It's hard to know without seeing more of your implementation, but you could, once you're out of the loop (meaning that the text is an integer) check the input in a different method. the above method only checks validity of the input.

Answer (score 2):

The `validateItemquantity()` method should return a true or false, based on whether the input is valid or not.

You can take care of the true and false cases in the function calling it. 
To take input, you could show an input dialog maybe.

```
String text = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Enter New Value"));
```

Answer (score 1):

If the user enters a wrong value your method would loop endlessly. If the method does not wait for the JOptionPane to close you will be confronted with an immesurable amount of dialog-popups.

You should let the method return a boolean value in any case and change some kind of "state", another boolean or some other kind of state-variable, in your programm if it succeeds.

If it doesn't you can let your state "loop" back to the point where the user has to enter a number and then let him restart the validation process, but in my opinion you should not restart the validation process on it's own when it fails.